# Trying to show html code via Javascript following all guidelines, but nothing is showing up

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show html code only for visitors who have Javascript enabled in their browsers.
The code is inside my `<body>` tag, but it is not executing. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?
Please note, that javascript is inside php `echo ' ';` Thats why Im using `\'` in javascript, so php can output it properly.

```
      <?php

       if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == false) {

        echo'
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = \'<div class="b_right">
      <div class="rezul">
        <a rel="nofollow" Id="'.base64_url_encode($url).'" href="javascript:void(0);" class="ftitle"><h4>'.$queryDOT.'</h4></a>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <div id="loadingmessage" style="display:none">
        <center><div class="preloader6"></div></center>
        </div>
        <div class="returned-details" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      </div>\';
}
</script>';
     
    }  ?>
```

On page, when looking source html I can see this code so seems like everything is working properly:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="b_right">
      <div class="rezul">
        <a rel="nofollow" Id="cmVrbGFtYWpld2VsIHF1ZXN0" href="javascript:void(0);" class="ftitle"><h4>Get this file</h4></a>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <div id="loadingmessage" style="display:none">
        <center><div class="preloader6"></div></center>
        </div>
        <div class="returned-details" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      </div>';
}
</script>
```

But nothing is showing up on page. Im also not getting any developer console errors ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks in Javascript need to be escaped with a "\" at the end of the line. Your JS code would need to look like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="b_right"> \
  <div class="rezul"> \
    <a rel="nofollow" Id="cmVrbGFtYWpld2VsIHF1ZXN0" href="javascript:void(0);" class="ftitle"><h4>Get this file</h4></a> \
    <div class="clear"> </div> \
    <div id="loadingmessage" style="display:none"> \
    <center><div class="preloader6"></div></center> \
    </div> \
    <div class="returned-details" style="display:none"></div> \
  </div> \
  </div>';
```

As the backslash also needs to be escaped in PHP this would end up in:

```
echo'
  <script>
    window.onload = function(){
      document.body.innerHTML = \'<div class="b_right"> \\
        <div class="rezul"> \\
          <a rel="nofollow" Id="'.base64_url_encode($url).'" href="javascript:void(0);" class="ftitle"><h4>'.$queryDOT.'</h4></a> \\
          <div class="clear"> </div> \\
          <div id="loadingmessage" style="display:none"> \\
            <center><div class="preloader6"></div></center> \\
          </div> \\
          <div class="returned-details" style="display:none"></div> \\
        </div> \\
      </div>\';
}
</script>';
```

**Regarding your question in the comments:**

adding or modifying the DOM Body via `document.body.innerHTML +=`  is messy so your idea to position the element in a container is preferable.

I would recommend to add your target container where the element should be displayed in in your HTML document with a unique ID:

```
<div id="target-container"></div>
```

And then instead of using `document.body.innerHTML` you would use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
document.getElementById("target-container").innerHTML = '...';
```

Comment: Ok, this helped, but now i see ONLY the html code in javascript, everything else on the website is gone (it shows website content for brief moment while page is loading and then only html from javascript) (Tho checking source code its showing whole website)

Comment: @DadaB But that is exactly what `document.body.innerHTML = ` does, it replaces the content of the BODY tag with the string value. If you want to append it, exchange it with `document.body.innerHTML += '...';` (which is messy) or [node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: Ok, its showing up now but at the bottom of the page. Any way of displaying it exactly in the position where I paste the code? Im really sorry, Im completely new to Javascript

Comment: @DadaB I added an example to my answer, see if that helps.